# Opening links using javascript, from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe

I made a custom google map using the api and in it are custom controls that link to pages. I made the map for a wordpress site but as it's a hassle for me to get the various javascript elements working natively, I created the map as a html file and uploaded it to the server and used an iframe to display it. The link buttons work fine when the map html is opened directly but when it's loaded into an iframe in the wordpress page, the buttons no longer work.

```
ButtonUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
window.parent.location.href= "LINK";
```

this is the snippet for the button, is there another way to implement the link that would work when the code is loaded by an iframe?